# Drupal 7: Can a module create a custom entity type and also custom fields it uses?

Tags: drupal-7, custom-field-type

I wrote a Drupal 7 module which defines a new entity type with `hook_entity_info()` et al. and several custom field types with `hook_field_info()` et al. that are required by this entity.  When the module is installed and enabled it is impossible to disable it because there is a circular dependency, the entity requires the fields that it defines.  Is there a way around this that I'm missing?  Or do I need to break this into two modules, one for the field and one for the entity?

Answer (score 1):

I think that, when you disable your module, you have to kill the instance of field on your node type before disabling it.

Try this to delete instance of fields:

```
$field_instance_to_delete = field_info_instance('node', $field_name, $nodetype);
field_delete_instance($field_instance_to_delete );
```